# Installing the Scripting Extension Python - SNAPSHOT JARs

Tags: scripting, python, extension

I am trying to install the Geoserver Scripting Extension - Python ([description](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/scripting/installation.html#python)). After downloading geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-python-plugin (my Geoserver is 2.17.0) I followed the instructions:

> Extract the contents of the archive into the /WEB-INF/lib/ directory
> of GeoServer. For example, if GeoServer was installed at
> /opt/geoserver-2.2.2/, extract the archive contents in
> /opt/geoserver-2.1.0/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib/.
>
> Restart GeoServer.

But - the scripting extension does not show in my menu.
Extension path is '/opt/tomcat/webapps/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib'.
Geoserver Version is 2.17.0.
In my lib folder I now find libraries like gt-process-geometry-23.0.jar    as well as    gt-process-geometry-23-SNAPSHOT.jar. Should I delete 'gt-process-geometry-23.0.jar'? This is the case (a ...23-SNAPSHOT.jar) with all the jar files included in 'geoserver-2.17-SNAPSHOT-python-plugin'. I assume that the SNAPSHOT jars include the Python Scripting Extension and no additional python.jar needs to be added? I therefor need to delete the files ending with geometry-23.0.jar?

EDIT: I did remove all '*-23.0.jar' and restarted. Still no scripting extension visible. What could be the possible problem? I recently instaled the WPS extension the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that scripting is not supported anymore.
See answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380787/how-can-i-access-scripts-in-geoserver) as well as the lacking packages in the corresponding [maxen repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geoserver.script/gs-script-py).